# bind user input to a field without using a button

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have an input text field in my web app where the user can type in some words. I want to be able to save that input into a variable in my bean without using an action command from a button. Ideally it would be a field that keeps a running track of what the user is entering and saving it in a variable.

Comment: Learn about a concept called ajax.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I've tried looking for an answer to this but haven't turned up anything. How does Ajax play into this?

Comment: Ajax is the solution to your 'problem'. That's how it plays into this. So first start reading on this, please...

Comment: look at this: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/event.xhtml